# Could not resolve archive.canonical..com

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

I am new to ubuntu and am trying to do a software install.  I am getting this error:

```
Could not resolve 'archive.canonical..com'
```

I've noticed there's an extra `.` in there.  Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For this open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file by:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

There are actually two lines with canonical in it, check them for the double `.` and remove one. Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to stop editing, press <kbd>y</kbd> to save and confirm the filename with a press on <kbd>return</kbd>.

Comment: For newbies, the graphical text editor might be easier to use than nano: `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list`

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` one liner should fix it:

```
sed -ri.bak 's/(archive\.canonical\.)\.(com)/\1\2/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Assuming the repositories are defined in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

To run it over the `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directories too:

```
sed -ri.bak 's/(archive\.canonical\.)\.(com)/\1\2/' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

The original file will be kept with a `.bak` extension.

If you do not want to keep a backup:

```
sed -ri 's/(archive\.canonical\.)\.(com)/\1\2/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Creating files with `.bak` in `sources.list.d` is not a good idea as it will throw errors over errors on the next `apt-get update` the only extensions in this directoy should be `.list` and `list.save`

Comment: @Videonauth I don't see any error message in my system. Also do you have any legitimate source to back that up?

Comment: O.k. has a question lately where someone had this problem `N: Ignoring file 'test.lit' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`.  This line is just from a test I just did, but it seems `.bak` is being ignored.

Comment: .save .bak .orig are the only supported that I'm aware of, that aren't .list obviously @videonauth

Comment: Wasn't aware of that this is why I commented.